# Adding duplicate rows in a db relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models joined by an association table:

```
class SKU(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sku'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    attributes = db.relationship('SKUAttribute', secondary=association_table, back_populates='skus')

class SKUAttribute(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    skus = db.relationship('SKU', secondary=association_table, back_populates='attributes')

association_table = db.Table('association_table',
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column('sku_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sku.id')),
    db.Column('sku_attribute_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sku_attribute.id')))
```

I want to add a column to the `SKU` that supplies a weight to each attribute that is appended:

```
attribute_weights = db.relationship('SKUAttributeWeight', ...
```

where SKUAttributeWeight weight table is specified in a similar way by:

```
class SKUAttributeWeight(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    sku_id = db.relationship('SKU', ....)
```

and populated with values:

```
id,value
1,0.0
2,0.5
3,1.0
```

So say a SKU has 2 (arbitrarily chosen) `attributes` assigned to them, I want to have their corresponding `attribute_weights` set to the same value, i.e. `value = 1.0` so `id = 3`.

However, when I add the same `attribute_weight` value 2 times, the list of attribute weights is only 1 element long as it removes duplicates.

How can I have this array be 2 elements long, i.e. containing `[SKUAttributeWeight.id=3, SKUAttributeWeight.id=3]` to match the length of the `attributes` array.

It seems the following might help, but can't piece it together:

[Can I append twice the same object to an InstrumentedList in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656715/can-i-append-twice-the-same-object-to-an-instrumentedlist-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Why would not you just extend the `association_table` to contain the weight instead of creating a whole new table to hold this information which needs to be synchronized? Read more on this in the [Association Object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) documentation.

Comment: @van Thanks ... I'll have a read :-)