# Support duplicate entries in a M2M associative table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a SQL-Alchemy app using flask and flask-db and have been scratching my head over how to solve this question. My models looks like this:

```
class event_schematics_map():
    event_schematics_table = db.Table(
        'event_schematics_table',
        db.Column('fk_schematic_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('schematics.id')),
        db.Column('fk_event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id'))
    )

class Events(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    owner = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    schematics = db.relationship('Recipe', secondary=event_schematics_map.event_schematics_table, backref='schematic')

class Schematics(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schematics'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(70), index=True)
    schematics_description = db.Column(db.String(1024), index=True)
    creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Schematics are created and are on the many side of O2M with a user table separately not shown above. The map table is used as the glue in the M2M relationship.

Currently I am adding new schematics to each event and updating the assoc table like so: `events.schematics.append(SomeNewSchematic)` which works fine until I attempt to enter multiple instances of the exact same Schematic like this:

```
schem1 = Schematics(name='TheOnlySchematic')
schem2 = Schematics(name='TheOnlySchematic')
event.schematics.append(schem1)
event.schematics.append(schem2)
etc
```

in which case I can only apply one as I think the entry is being duplicated. I believe this may be solved by an additional field in the assoc table event_schematics_map, but unsure if I am overlooking something simpler or how to implement this.

Effectively I want to support multiple entries of the exact same model

I believe my problem is along the same lines as [can I append twice the same object to an instrumentedlist in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656715/can-i-append-twice-the-same-object-to-an-instrumentedlist-in-sqlalchemy) - but I could not see a solution for this.

Really appreciate any pointers or to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Having an exact duplicate in a many-to-many relationship doesn't make any sense unless there is some other attribute associated with the link, such as a date or a version number or something like that. In that case you'd need to add that attribute to your association class (event_schematics_map) to track that piece of information and to make the rows in the association table unique.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply and setting me straight here,

You are quite right, duplicate entries does not make sense.

I ended up solving this by using an associative table as discussed in other answers to track the occurrence of each schematic.